# Storybook will not install: Could not resolve dependency: peer react@"^18.2.0"

Tags: reactjs, npm, storybook

I want to initialize Storybook in a root directory which contains several front-end component library implementations

```bash
project/
// Storybook should be initialized here...
    vue-library/
    twig-library/
    svelte-library/
```

When I try to run any of these commands in the `project/` directory I get an error.

```bash
npm install @storybook/cli
npx storybook init
```

The error:

```bash
npm WARN
Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
While resolving: react-dom@18.2.0
Found: peer react@"^18.2.0" from the root project.
```

I tried initializing storybook from inside the `vue-library/` folder as well, and I received the same error.

I also tried to install `react` as a peer dependency on my own by manually adding the peer dependency to a `package.json` in the `project/` directory:

```json
{
  "name": "********-********-*********",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "*********************************"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@storybook/cli": "^6.5.9"
  },
  "peerDependencies": { 
    "react": "^18.2.0"  <-------------- ADDED THIS
  },
  "author": "**** **",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

This didn't solve the problem, though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually install `react` and `react-dom` as `"devDependencies"` in the project root directory.

```
npm install -D react react-dom @storybook/cli
```

Your concept of `"peerDependencies"` is likely wrong. A package’s peer dep means, it’s a dep which the package cannot live without, nonetheless, the package is expecting someone else to take care of the installation.

This might sound weird but it helps avoid duplicate dependency installation. Read [this article](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/) for detail.

---

I just create an empty `test/` folder to test run. It works on my machine<sup>TM</sup>.

```bash
➜  test npm install -D react react-dom @storybook/cli

# ...

added 1026 packages in 41s

➜  test npx storybook init

Need to install the following packages:
  storybook
Ok to proceed? (y) y

# ...

✨  Done in 44.47s.
. ✓
 • Preparing to install dependencies. ✓


yarn install v1.22.19

[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 1.13s.
. ✓
 checking possible migrations..

✅ migration check successfully ran

To run your Storybook, type:

   yarn storybook 

For more information visit: https://storybook.js.org
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Causing another error. I'm using my company's repo. Perhaps it has a problem?
```sh
ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
While resolving: *******-******-******@0.0.1
Found: react@undefined
node_modules/react
   dev react@"*" from the root project
Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
node_modules/react-dom
   dev react-dom@"*" from the root project
Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: Sorry for that horribly formatted comment.

Comment: This info isn't sufficient for me to debug further. I just tested the command and it works, see updated section of my answer. Must be sth else you haven't mentioned in your post. Couldn't guess what. Edit your post to provide more info pls. Error log, package.json, etc.

Comment: Another advice, try remove every `node_modules/` folders in your project. Start from scratch and reinstall packages.